# Distributed compiling for C#/VB.NET in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm looking for a way to compile our application a bit faster, and there is a lot of dead time now. Doing a little research I've found out 
about [IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com/), but the way I understand it, it only speeds up building for C++.

Is there a way to speed up a Visual Studio 2010 solution of multiple VB.NET/C# projects?

Comment: How much time are we talking about here?

Comment: Takes about 10 mins to compile.

Comment: Do you have to compile everything every time?

Comment: No, but often enough I'm forced to rebuild due to a bad project setup. I'll remake the project when I have the time but I figured that I would see if there were any grid-compiling solutions that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **MSBuild /m** (for multi-threaded compilation)

More information here:

*[Building Multiple Projects in Parallel with MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/building-multiple-projects-in-parallel-with-msbuild?view=vs-2015)*

*[Hack: Parallel MSBuilds from within the Visual Studio IDE](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx)*

Comment: Though useful and interesting, not really what I asked about. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: This answer looks germane to me. Are you really asking about people's experience with IncrediBuild?

Comment: Is this still applicable for VS2017 or is it done by default now?

Comment: @rolls it still applies. Default value for /m switch is 1.